# How do I run an executable in a directory I added to PATH?

Tags: command-line, bash

I added a directory to my `PATH` by doing `PATH=$PATH:~/Documents/Clang` but when I type `./clang`, Bash says `No such file or directory`.

Why is that?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading `./` forces Bash to search for the exectuable in the current working directory (`~`).

Make sure your user has execute permission on it: if you're the owner (you should be since apparently you either downloaded Clang's binary or compiled Clang from source):

- `chmod u+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang` to grant the permission to yourself;
- `chmod ug+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang` to grant the permission to yourself and to the owner group;
- `chmod a+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang` to grant the permission to yourself, to the owner group and to everyone else.

And then just type the name of the executable:

```
clang
```

```
% cat ~/tmp/script.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf 'foo\n'
% PATH=$PATH:~/tmp
% ./script.sh
bash: ./script.sh: No such file or directory
% script.sh
foo
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, bash says: `The program 'clang' can be found in the following packages:
 * clang-3.3
 * clang-3.4
 * clang-3.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Comment: @GeekusMaximus Are you sure the executable is named exactly `clang`? If it is make sure it's executable from your user (if you own it `chmod u+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang`, to grant the permission also to the group `chmod ug+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang` and to grant permissions also to the others `chmod a+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang`).

Comment: You don't have clang installed where you say you do. It is not typical for it to be in a local Docs directory, and bash isn't finding it there it anywhere in the path. Did you actually install it with a package manager?

Comment: Yeah `chmod ug+x ~/Documents/Clang/clang` worked. Thanks.

Comment: @jdv I put it there. Didn't use the package manager.

Comment: @GeekusMaximus No problem. If this answer helped you, [you may accept it as well](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).